# How to add a condition before append in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 graph in which nodes have types specified in JSON. Depending on the type I would like to append a rect or circle and follow with additional attributes etc. Can anybody enlighten me on the best approach to do that?

I've tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6qAbZ/1/) but ended up with

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

error.

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .attr("opacity",1)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
        })


// if (d.type == "s")   {  

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("fill", function(d,i) {return colorOrdinal(i) } )
        .attr("opacity",1)
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .attr("width",130)
        .attr("height",14)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "rotate(" + (d.x - d.x ) + ")translate(" + (d.y -d.y + 0) + "," + -7 + ")";
        })

//}
//else
//{
    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr("opacity",1)  
        .style("fill", function(d,i) { return colorOrdinal(i) } )     
// }
    node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .attr("opacity",1)
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

Comment: Looks like the error is caused by trying to append a String. `"rect"` is a String.

Comment: I tried to kick of with `node.append(function(d){return (d.type == "s" ? "rect" : "")})` then follow with the rest fo `.attr`. This gave me an error

Comment: why don't you post your current fiddle?

Comment: Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39288730/4235784) to [*"How to create SVG elements of different types based on data?"*](/q/39278704).

Comment: Thank you @altocumulus. Indeed, it looks like this is what I'm looking for.