# D3 filter geojson by geometry

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, geojson

I am new to D3.js and I would like to create a map from a .geojson file.

How could I filter my data to include svg circles from my Geojson **Points** and paths from my Geojson **LineStrings** in a clean way ?

Something like :

```
d3.json("static/data/test.geojson", function (data) {

svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append(function (d){
          if (d.geometry.type == "Point") {
            return "circle"
          } else if (d.geometry.type == "LineString") {
            return "path"
          }
        })

 })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create SVG elements of different types based on data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278704/how-to-create-svg-elements-of-different-types-based-on-data)

Comment: As it is now, the question is a duplicate. However, I am afraid, you didn't even ask the right question ;-) Are you aware of the mighty [d3-geo](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo) module, which will do all the heavy lifting for you? There is no need to create all those SVG elements on your own. Just hand the GeoJSON over to D3 and—lo and behold—out comes a map.