# Append shapes dynamically in d3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to `append` a shape dynamically, based on what is contained with the `datum`. My object is this:

```
const boom = [
  {
    shape: 'rect',
    color: 'red',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    x: 50,
    y: 100
  }
]
```

And my code is this:

```
const stage = d3.select('stageContainer')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .style('border-width', '2')
    .style('border-color', 'red')
    .style('border-style', 'solid')

stage.selectAll('.group01')
      .data(boom)
      .enter()
      .append(d => document.createElement(d.shape))
      .attr('fill', d => d.color)
      .attr('width', d => d.width)
      .attr('height', d => d.height)
      .attr('x', d => d.x)
      .attr('y', d => d.y)
```

I can see that it's adding to the DOM, but it isn't actually rendering.

Comment: try `.append(d => d.shape)`

Comment: Tried that. I keep getting: `"TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."`

Comment: Now I read the docs carefully and if it is a function it has to return a different type compared to a constant string. The method should be able to handle different function returns (including a string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating SVG elements you have to use `document.createElementNS`:

```
.append(d => document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', d.shape))
```

Alternatively, you can use the built-in namespaces in `d3.namespaces`:

```
.append(d => document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, d.shape))
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const boom = [{
  shape: 'rect',
  color: 'blue',
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  x: 40,
  y: 10
}];

const stage = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('border-width', '2')
  .style('border-color', 'red')
  .style('border-style', 'solid')

stage.selectAll('.group01')
  .data(boom)
  .enter()
  .append(d => document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, d.shape))
  .attr('fill', d => d.color)
  .attr('width', d => d.width)
  .attr('height', d => d.height)
  .attr('x', d => d.x)
  .attr('y', d => d.y)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

PS: change that rectangle's position, otherwise it will fall outside the SVG.

Comment: Also, the stage dimensions were just demonstrative, but thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Despite this question having an accepted answer, would you mind dupe-hammering this as a duplicate of [*"How to create SVG elements of different types based on data?"*](/q/39278704)?

Comment: @altocumulus Done, it's actually just the same. That didn't show up in the search I made (S.O search mechanism is not exactly brilliant). But now I cannot delete my answer...

Comment: @altocumulus: I have found an alternative way (no namespaces) and have added it as an answer to  the previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/51860323/9938317

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip about the title. Appreciate that, and will remember for the future :)