# D3 JS - Why d3 is not appending a string?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this `json` file:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Hello world",
        "shape": "rect",
        "fill": "pink"
    }
]
```

And I also have this `javascript` file:

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg')
var stringToHTML = function (str) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
    return doc.body;
};
d3.json("tree.json").then(data => {
    const elements = svg.selectAll('*')
        .data(data);
    elements.enter()
        .append("rect")
            .attr("x", 20)
            .attr("y", 20)
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .attr("fill", d => d.fill)
    elements.enter()
        .append('text')
            .attr("x", 50)
            .attr("y", 60)
            .html("text", d => {d.name})
    
})
```

and this `html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg width="600" height="600">
    </svg>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now the output is:

[1st output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyNtt.png)

but when I switch `"rect"` with `d => d.shape` it doesn't behave as before.

```js
d3.json("tree.json").then(data => {
    const elements = svg.selectAll('*')
        .data(data);
    elements.enter()
        .append(d => d.)
            .attr("x", 20)
            .attr("y", 20)
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .attr("fill", d => d.fill)
```

But how is it different than the previous one? I also tried outputting `d.shape`, and it prints `string`. Then how can I make something that will create a shape according to the shape data?

Comment: Check the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_append), you have to use `document.createElement` or, in your case, `document.createElementNS`. This answer explains how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39288730/5768908

Comment: But why does my code not work?

Comment: *"If the specified type is a function, it is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]). This function should return an element to be appended."*. The element, not a string.